# Discord Bot Offline

Tags: python, heroku, nextcord

I coded my bot using nextcord and tried running it 24/7 using Heroku. However, there are no error codes when I deploy my bot, it stays offline. I've used heroku before for my discord-py bots, they all work. This is the first time I am adding slash commands (that work when I run it on my pc) to my bots. I have all the files I need such as requirements.txt, Procfile, runtime.txt and index.py, stored in the same git repo. How do I fix this?

requirement.txt:

```
nextcord==2.0.0
```

runtime.txt:

```
python-3.10.6
```

procfile:

```
worker: python3 index.py
```

I have the worker dyno enabled

Comment: Check the logs (More > view logs). If the bot doesn't start, either the deployment failed or it will tell you the problem in the logs. You can also view additional logs with the CLI or using a free add-on such as Papertrail.